# ACF image field in foreach loop for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I want to load my ACF field cat_img inside of this loop where it says `$cat->image`. The existing code block I am working with is:

```
<?php 
      $cats = get_categories($image = get_field('cat_img'));
      foreach ($cats as $cat) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mb-4 mx-auto">
          <div class="bg-image ripple rounded-5" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
            <img class="w-100" src="<?php $cat->image ?>"
              style="height: 288px; object-fit: cover" />
            <a href="'. get_term_link($cat).'">
              <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                  <p class="h4 fw-bold text-uppercase text-dark mb-0"><?php echo $cat->name ?></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="hover-overlay">
                <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.1)"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php  ;
      }
      ?>
```

any help on how to get it to show that custom field would be awesome. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Assuming your category itsself has ACF fields you would get them within the loop by calling ``$image = get_fields($cat->ID, 'fieldname')``. Then  you can do something like ``echo $image['url']``.

Comment: @Frizzant I tried that at first and had no luck with it. Is it possibly something to do with the image type being URL or array?

Comment: It should not. Where I have worked so far, we always use image ID. Then you can reliably get what you need, instead of being presented with data you don't neccessarily need. This should have nothing to do with you solution however.

If you install "kint debugger" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/kint-php-debugger/) locally, you can enter ``ddd($cat)`` and see what's available. The same you can do with any variable. Quite useful, if you don't have a "real" PHP debugger installed.
It might help you find a solution.

Comment: I am wondering if I need to make it args to pass into the forEach loop. I just realized the way you are passing it would be on a template that would be in a category page or something. This is outside the WordPress loop and a custom foreach loop to cerate tiles for each category.

Comment: found the exact answer. @Frizzant you were on the right track, just needed different argument parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing this line inside my forEach loop:

```
$image = get_field('cat_img', 'category_' . $cat->term_id );
```

That lets me now run this block of code to get ACF field images as tiles behind the category name (you will see the `<? echo $image['url']?>` where the image is called):

```
<?php
      
      $cats = get_categories();
      foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $image = get_field('cat_img', 'category_' . $cat->term_id );
      ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3 mb-4 mx-auto">
          <div class="bg-image ripple rounded-5" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
            <img class="w-100" src="<? echo $image['url']?>"
              style="height: 288px; object-fit: cover" alt="<? echo get_field('cat_img', $cat->ID) ?> Category Image"/>
            <a href="<? echo get_term_link($cat);?>">
              <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.35)">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                  <p class="h4 fw-bold text-uppercase text-light mb-0"><?php echo $cat->name ?></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="hover-overlay">
                <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.1)"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php  ;
      }
      ?>
```